# Extracting a value from XML and storing it in a variable

Tags: css, xml, xslt, web

here is my sample XML :

```
<Entries>
    <Entry>
       <id>1</id>
     .
     .
     </Entry>

     <Entry>
       <id>2</id>
       <assets> 
          <TextAssetInfo>
             <Name>Alpha</Name>
             <TagName>alphaName</TagName>
             <value>Harambe</value>
          </TextAssetInfo>
       </assets>
     </Entry>
<Entries>
```

So my goal is simply to extract the value of Alpha and store it in a variable in my XSLT for further computation.

I am able extract and print the value. But not assign in to a variable.

Following part of XSL code works:

```
<T_AlphaName><xsl:value-of select="./assets/*[TagName = 'alphaName']/value"/></T_AlphaName>
```

However, I can't get the below to work :

```
 <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="./assets/*[TagName = 'alphaName']/value"/>
```

I have tried many other combinations as well but no luck. What am I doing wrong? In my XSL I have part to test it and get a weird result

```
<TestVar><xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/></TestVar>

 Result : <TestVar/>
```

Additional info : 
Using XML/XSL version 1.0. 
AlphaName is not the only TextAssetInfo inside the assets. There are many more.

Comment: Is the "attrTagName" in your `xsl:variable/@select` a typo?

Comment: Hi Telic, 

Thank You for the prompt response. But I am sorry I don't see that. 

I have it as following : 

     <xsl:variable name="myVar" select="./assets/*[attrTagName = 'alphaName']/value"/>

Comment: The selection in your variable code is different from the selection in your "working" code. One has `[Tagname = 'alphaName']` and the other has `[attrTagName = 'alphaName']`

Comment: .. neither of which actually appear in your sample XML...

Comment: Can you show a small, but complete, sample of XSLT that demonstrates the problem, please? It might be a scope issue, for example. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Tim. 

Thanks for the response. I figured it out. It was a simple scope/path issue (relatively new to XSLT). 

 I needed the following for the variable :                         
    

      <T_AlphaName><xsl:value-of select="./Entries/Entry/assets/*[TagName = 'alphaName']/value"/></T_AlphaName>


Thank You all.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own questions, as the aim of SO is for questions to be of benefit to other users who encounter similar issues.

Comment: ... or if you do not intend to do that, then since you no longer need an answer, you should delete this as-yet unanswered question.